# upload & download file in either csv,html or xml extension

Tags: java, web-services, download, upload

I am working on a project web service using java, one service should be user can request file from my machine (project file system) to download in either  csv,html or xml extension.

I do not know how to upload file and create download link . Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use apache poi for generation of excel from your service layer.Normal servlet with jsp can be used in your view layer for upload and download your excel.

check this out..

http://www.javatpoint.com/downloading-file-from-the-server-in-jsp

http://www.javatpoint.com/uploading-file-to-the-server-in-jsp